# How to make sure your dealloc code is called on application termination?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, destructor, dealloc

According to NSObject's documentation:

> Important: Note that when an
>   application terminates, objects may
>   not be sent a dealloc message since
>   the process's memory is automatically
>   cleared on exit --- it is more
>   efficient simply to allow the
>   operating system to clean up resources
>   than to invoke all the memory
>   management methods.

That's fine, but if my objects **needs** to do something on dealloc, such as saving its state to disk or log something?  How can I make sure that code gets called?

Comment: You can use NSLog on termination and read the log after the app has been terminated to check whether it pass the dealloc methos or not.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Persistency management should not be tied to `dealloc`. If you want to save object state, you should have some kind of session object that will collect the dirty objects and save the changes once in a while or when the application terminates/goes into background.

An example using application settings: Let’s say you don’t want to use `NSUserDefaults` for you application’s settings, maybe because you have some extra logic to do. You have a `Settings` class that keeps all the settings and obviously you would like to keep the changes persisted.

You could stuff all the persistency logic into the `Settings` class, but that violates the single responsibility principle. (= There are good reasons why this would cause you pain.) So you could add a `Session` class that will take of persisting the changes made in `Settings`.

When the application starts you will create an instance of the `Session` and ask for `Settings`:

```
Session *session = [[Session alloc] init];
Settings *settings = [session loadSettings];
```

Now if there is a file on the disk that contains saved settings, the session will load it (which is simple, as the `Settings` class implements `NSCoding`). If not, the session will create a fresh `Settings` instance and return that. In addition, the session will probably start watching for changes in the returned `Settings` instance, say using `NSNotificationCenter`. (It’s quite natural that a `Settings` object would fire a notification when the settings change.)

Now when you change something inside a `Settings` instance that you got from the session, the session will notice that and it will save the changes to disk. Which should be trivial, since `Settings` implement `NSCoding`. You could also mark the object as dirty and only save the changes every few seconds, which is a better solution in case you update the object quite frequently. In that case you might also want to force-save the session when the application is going to terminate or is going background.

I’m not saying this scenario is perfect, but it’s certainly better than objects that persist themselves in dealloc :-)

Comment: Could you elaborate on this please? O:-)

Answer (score 5):

Make sure the object gets released in your `applicationWillTerminate:` (`NSApplicationDelegate`).

Comment: It doesn't have to be in the delegate. You can observe for `NSApplicationWillTerminateNotification` on the local notification center.